# start google chrome without switches

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, windows-7

Is there a way to start google chrome without switches?

Is there a file where I can see and manage all current enabled switches?

If I enter `chrome://version` in the URL, I can see that currently there are some enabled switches
 that I can't find under `chrome://flags`, and I need to know if is there some file where they are stored, and if can I edit it, or if can I start chrome from command line without switches..

Please help

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am assuming this has started since last update (chrome beta 40ish last week or so). Funny thing is when I run it through the console, I end up with switched anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Try `start chrome`.
You can also go to "Run..." by pressing "Windows Key" + R, and type `chrome`.

Comment: I've already tried to launch chrome in this way, but all the switches are still enabled.. I can see it entering the url: "chrome://version"

Comment: Well then, I don't know how to help you. The only versions of Windows I own are 95, 98, ME, XP, and 7.

Comment: I'm sad about your win version disponibility

Comment: Wait... oh your using win 7 too (just looked at tags) I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chrome --help` to see the switches.

Also there is a [web page](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that list all switches